# C# DocX : add internal link

Tags: c#, .net, novacode-docx

In the DocX library available at : https://github.com/WordDocX/DocX

It is possible to add some hyperlink but i haven't found a way to add internal link.

Does anyone know how to add a link to specific paragraph or to a bookmark ?

Comment: have you tried just linking to #bookmarkwhatever?

Comment: How ? Any code sample ?

Comment: link to #bookmarkwhatever - same way you link to any other link

Comment: I know how an internal link is constructed, i want to know if there is a way to do it with the DocX library, and how ? How means, i want to see a real example and what function/method/property you are using. To add an hyperlink you type that : Hyperlink h = myDocxDocument.AddHyperlink("Link", "http://www.google.com"); synthesisDocument.Paragraphs[0].InsertHyperlink(h); and obviously if you type that : Hyperlink h = synthesisDocument.AddHyperlink("Link", "#MY_BOOKMARK");synthesisDocument.Paragraphs[0].InsertHyperlink(h); it doesnt work.

Comment: Ok i think you are trolling... of course i did some research !! On google AND StackOverflow

Comment: So you do not understand what i am asking for... stop flooded if you don't intend to help

Comment: I did actually but you keep telling yourself that - considering the fact I was the only one trying to help you. you shot yourself in the foot

Comment: Thank you for trying to help, but when i ask for a code sample and you answer this "link to #bookmarkwhatever - same way you link to any other link" it's quite insulting....   and totally wrong as the code sample i sent demonstrate. If you don't know the answer... fine... admit it and stop the useless flood pls. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I've found is:

`synthesisDocument.AddHyperlink("Link",new Uri("file:///path/to/doc/file.doc#MY_BOOKMARK"));
synthesisDocument.Paragraphs[0].InsertHyperl‌​ink(h)`

That way resolve your problem, but only in doc format, when you export to PDF it doesn't work.
I hope it helps

Comment: This is the best clue i found, I can definitly start to work with that, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned #BookMark does work if the Uri is created with the UriKind.Relative flag:

```
 var uri = new Uri("#" + BookMark,UriKind.Relative);
 var hyperLink =  doc.AddHyperlink(textToDisplay, uri  );
```

Now to use the hyperlink on a paragraph, p:

```
 p.InsertHyperlink(hyperLink,indexToInsertAt);
```

I achieved exactly the result I wanted using this in both .docx and .pdf

Hope it works for you,

Nick